# Signing messages using PublishToAzureServiceBus task

Tags: azure-devops, azureservicebus, x509certificate2

I'm trying to sign a message using the task PublishToAzureServiceBus. I am using a certificate that is stored in keyvault and using the AzureKeyVault task to download the secret.

My yaml for the step looks like this:

```
- task: PublishToAzureServiceBus@1
inputs:
azureSubscription: 'AsbQueue'
messageBody: |
{
--Redacted--
}
certificateString: $(signingCert)
signPayload: true
waitForCompletion: true
signatureKey: 'signature'
```

I've tried several different types of certificate. But I always get this error:

```
JsonWebTokens do not support crypto provider of type 1.
```

Is this down to the cryptographic provider im using to create the cert? If so which one should I be using?

Comment: Is there any evidence from your point of view that the error message is correct i.e. there is a JWT involved somewhere, or is this nonsense? It _sounds_ like it's saying it can't sign that type of content because it recognises it's a JWT and adding a signature would make it invalid - but I don't see any reason to think that.

Comment: I don't think jwt should be involved at all. The task shouldn't have knowledge that my message is json and all it should be doing is sticking a signature header on the message having performed a straightforward signing of the bytes. The body of the message is just standard json, it's not a token.